# JS: Repeat and randomise an array X times so that the value in the last last index is not the same as in the previous iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

I have an array that has been randomised and repeated X times. How can I ensure for each iteration that the last item in the array is not the same as in the previous iteration?

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    shuffle(arr);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Example output:

```
[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 5]
[6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2] 
[1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2] // Last item in array is same as last item in previous array
[6, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 6]
```

**What I'd like to be output:**

```
[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 5]
[6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4] // Last item in array is different to last item in previous array
[6, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 6]
```

I'm guessing I need to do something along the lines of storing the previous and current arrays in a temporary variable but have so far been unsuccessful at generating the correct logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps, you could just check for the case and if this is the case, just push your array to left or right by 1 item. This way you never have the same row in, at most, one more step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a push to left each time you have the problem, here it is a solution using a previousLast global variable (perhaps you should wrap all in a class to be cleaner) :

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var previousLast = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    // here you should reassign arr because, if arr is rolled, this is a new array.
    arr = shuffle(arr);
    console.log(arr);
}

function rollLeft(a) {
    var b = [];
    for(var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        b.push(a[(i + 1) % n]);
    }
    return b;
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  if(array[array.length - 1] == previousLast) {
    array = rollLeft(array);
  }

  previousLast = array[array.length - 1];

  return array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sébastien Doncker. When I run this through the console I'm still getting the following example output:
[2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6]
[4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6]
[4, 2, 3, 6, 1, 5]
[6, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5]
[1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6]
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I edit my code. I forgot but you have to use arr=shuffle(arr) because when the array is rolled left, my function create a new array and he as to be reassign to the arr variable. If you don't want to create a new array, you could change the rollLeft function to do the same thing without create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop.

```
while(new_array[new_array.length - 1] == old_array[old_array.length - 1]) {
    // Do some randomising
}
```

Obviously it's a bit of a stretch to call this random anymore though.